# Dealing with expired ClickOnce certificates and signing

Tags: certificate, clickonce

I have a ClickOnce application deployed on our internal network. As this is only an "internal" application, I don't really need an "officially signed" certificate for any reason. When I went to publish an update today, I got the error message

> The signers's certificate is not valid for signing.

When I check the "Signing" tab in Visual Studio 2010, I can see that I am past the expiration date. I know that I created this TemporaryKey using the "Create Test Certificate" button on this same tab in Visual Studio.

In the past, I just created a new test certificate, and used that. This essentially "buys" me another year until I have to do this all over again. I would like to correctly sign a new certificate that is good for X number of years (or never expires).

I have done some research, but as I am unfamiliar with this whole scenario, the nomenclature is extremely confusing. I can follow instructions, but only if they are written in a manner that an intermediate user can understand. Is there a reference that explains this process step by step, hopefully with screenshots? I can't believe with all my looking around I haven't found this already, so I must not be looking up the relevant keywords.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Xenos Certificate Generator](http://www.xenossoftware.com/free-tools/certificate-generator/), a free tool that will allow you to create a certificate with x number of days until expiration.

Comment: Adel - That tool worked great. The only caveat was that I couldn't update the app via code inside my app. I got some sort of security warning when I did so. Therefore, I just restarted the app and let ClickOnce handle the update, which worked. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

For future reference, here is [all the information you ever wanted about expiring certificates in ClickOnce deployments.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff369721.aspx)  It also shows you how to create a certificate and set the date range for which it is valid.